# Unsigned char c = 255 is "11111111" or not?

Tags: c, binary, char

Here is my problem code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
        char a = -1;
        unsigned char b = 255;
        unsigned char c = 0;
        if((~a) ==  c)
                printf("OK 1");
        else
                printf("bad 1");
        printf("\n");
        if((~b) ==  c)
                printf("OK 2");
        else
                printf("bad 2");
        printf("\n");
}
```

I expected this to print:

```
OK 1

OK 2
```

But, I get OK 1 and bad 2!

If `unsigned char b` is 255 (11111111), then ~b should be 00000000. Why does it not equal c?

I work on Linux SUSE, using gcc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're getting bitten by integer promotions.  When you do:

```
~b == c
```

`b` and `c` both get promoted to `int`.  That means you're really doing:

```
~0x000000ff == 0
```

That ends up comparing:

```
0xffffff00 == 0
```

Which don't match.  It works in your first case because your `char` type is signed, and gets sign extended in the promotion:

```
~a == c
~(-1) == 0
~0xffffffff == 0
0 == 0
```

Comment: ~0x000000ff is not 0xffffff00. It's -0x100.

Comment: R.. is right.  I'm just showing bit patterns in the answer, which is probably a poor choice given the C-standard-related subtlety of what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Because of standard integral promotions: In the expression `~b`, the operand is promoted to `int`, which could be something like `0x000000FF`; the result is the integer `0xFFFFFF00`.

You have to convert the result back to `unsigned char`:

```
if ((unsigned char)(~b) == c) /* ... */
```

Comment: @CarlNorum: In my notation, `F` is the 256th symbol :-)