# Is unsigned char always promoted to int?

Tags: c, type-conversion, c99, integer-promotion, type-promotion

Suppose the following:

```
unsigned char foo = 3;
unsigned char bar = 5;

unsigned int shmoo = foo + bar;
```

Are `foo` and `bar` values guaranteed to be promoted to `int` values for the evaluation of the expression `foo + bar` -- or are implementations allowed to promote them to `unsigned int`?

In **section 6.2.5** paragraph 8:

> For any two integer types with the same signedness and different integer conversion rank
>   (see 6.3.1.1), the range of values of the type with smaller integer conversion rank is a
>   subrange of the values of the other type.

In **section 6.2.5** paragraph 9:

> If an **`int`** can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an **`int`**; otherwise, it is converted to an **`unsigned int`**.

The guarantee that an integer type with smaller integer conversion rank has a range of values that is a subrange of the values of the other type seems dependent on the *signedness* of the integer type.

- `signed char` corresponds to `signed int`
- `unsigned char` corresponds to `unsigned int`

Does this mean that the value of an `unsigned char` is only guaranteed to be in the subrange of `unsigned int` and not necessarily `int`? If so, does that imply that an implementation could theoretically have an `unsigned char` value which is not in the subrange of an `int`?

Comment: [Deep C: Integer Promotion](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/)

Comment: Unless you find a system where int is 8 bits it should work as section 6.2.5 paragraph 9 points out.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I think that website is assuming the minimum magnitudes for the integer types. I believe implementations are only required to support these minimum magnitudes, but are allowed to define the range magnitudes to be greater (section 5.2.4.2.1: `Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.`).

Comment: @VilhelmGray I just asked because it seems you are posting related questions,.. Well @ Ouah is  helping you so, good luck!

Comment: @hetepeperfan In a standard C compiler, `int` has to be at least 16 bits, but nothing prevents `unsigned char` to be as wide as `int` (for instance both 24-bit) in which case `unsigned char` would promote to `unsigned int`.

Comment: Read this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869967/unsigned-char-c-255-is-11111111-or-not

Comment: @PascalCuoq Good point, I mistakenly assumed (unsigned) char to be 8 bits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> are implementations allowed to promote them to unsigned int?

Implementations will promote to `unsigned int` if not all `unsigned char` values are representable in an `int` (as ruled by 6.2.5p9 in C99). See below for implementation examples.

> If so, does that imply that an implementation could theoretically have an unsigned char value which is not in the subrange of an int?

Yes, example: DSP cpu with `CHAR_BIT` 16 or 32.

For example, TI C compiler for TMS320C55x: `CHAR_BIT` is 16 and `UCHAR_MAX` 65535, `UINT_MAX` 65535 but `INT_MAX` 32767.

http://focus.ti.com/lit/ug/spru281f/spru281f.pdf

Comment: I believe this possibility is the reason that it must be possible for `char` to be signed (since all values of `char` must fit within `int`).  Conversely, the requirement that all members of the C character set forces some compilers to have `char` be unsigned (e.g. in EBCDIC I think the digits 0-9 are 0xF0-0xF9).

Comment: If I have something like this `int x = 1234` and `char *y = &x` . Binary representation of `1234 ` is `00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010` . My machine is little endian so it reverses it and store in memory `11010010 00000100 00000000 00000000` LSB comes first. Now Main Part . if i use `printf("%d" , *p)`. `printf` will read first byte `11010010`only the output is `-46` but `11010010` is `210` so why does it print `-46` . I am really confused i guess some char to integer promotion is doing something but i don't know.

Comment: @SurajJain I think you mean `printf("%d" , *y)`. `d` specifier writes a signed value and `11010010` is `-46` in two's complement representation. Use `printf("%d" , (unsigned char) *y)` to write the unsigned value. If you have more questions, can I suggest to open a stackoverflow question?

Comment: Sir , i opened a Question And When i founded answer i wrote it , i wanted it to get checked since months , can you please do it for me , i just wanted to confirm that what i wrote was correct and would not lead anyone in wrong direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826036/confused-about-pointer-dereferencing

Comment: @SurajJain comment added.

Comment: Does using  %d for printing char defined? John Bode Says It is not.

Comment: @SurajJain "%d" expects to match an `int` argument.  `char` are passed to `...` functions as `int` or rarely `unsigned`.  When passed as `unsigned` and still in range of `[0...INT_MAX]` all is well.  Else UB.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this yesterday - hope that my answer is on topic.

```
uint8_t x =  10;
uint8_t y = 250;

if (x - y > 0) {
    // never happens
}

if (x - y < 0U) {
    // always happens
}
```

To my eyes at least it was appearing as though values x and y were being unexpectedly promoted, when in fact is was their result that was promoted.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. x and y are both supposed to be promoted to int so you should have -240 which is then promoted to unsigned for the comparison (4294967056 < 0U) which should never happen.