# Is the %c fprintf specifier required to take an int argument

Tags: c, c99, language-lawyer, printf, variadic-functions

In **section 7.19.6.1** paragraph 8 of the C99 standard:

> **`c`** If no **`l`** length modifier is present, the **`int`** argument is converted to an
>   **`unsigned char`**, and the resulting character is written.

In **section 7.19.6.1** paragraph 9 of the C99 standard:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

- Does the `fprintf` function require an `int` argument?

For example, would passing an `unsigned int` result in undefined behavior:

```
unsigned int foo = 42;

fprintf(fp, "%c\n", foo); /* undefined behavior? */
```

This worries me since an implementation could have defined `char` as having the same behavior as `unsigned char` (**section 6.2.5** paragraph 15).

For these cases integer promotion may dictate that the `char` to be [promoted to `unsigned int` on some implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17882460/1806289). Thus leaving the following code to risk undefined behavior on those implementations:

```
char bar = 'B';

fprintf(fp, "%c\n", bar); /* possible undefined behavior? */
```

- Are `int` variables and literal `int` constants the only safe way to pass a value to `fprintf` with the `%c` specifier?

Comment: Well you could always write `fprintf(fp, "%c\n", 'B');`.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot character constants are of type `int` in C, aren't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `printf` with `"%c"` requires an `int` argument -- more or less.

If the argument is of a type narrower than `int`, then it will be *promoted*. In most cases, the promotion is to `int`, with well defined behavior. In the very rare case that plain `char` is unsigned and `sizeof (int) == 1` (which implies `CHAR_BIT >= 16`), a `char` argument is promoted to `unsigned int`, which *can* cause undefined behavior.

A character constant is already of type `int`, so `printf("%c", 'x')` is well defined even on exotic systems. (Off-topic: In C++, character constants are of type `char`.)

This:

```
unsigned int foo = 42;
fprintf(fp, "%c\n", foo);
```

*strictly speaking* has undefined behavior.  [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.1.4p1 says:

> If an argument to a function has ... a type (after promotion) not
>   expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior
>   is undefined.

and the `fprintf` call clearly runs afoul of that. (Thanks to ouah for pointing that out.)

On the other hand, 6.2.5p6 says:

> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but
>   different) unsigned integer type (designated with the keyword
>   **unsigned**) that uses the same amount of storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements.

and 6.2.5p9 says:

> The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange
>   of the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the representation of
>   the same value in each type is the same.

with a footnote:

> The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply
>   interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from
>   functions, and members of unions.

The footnote says that function arguments of types `int` and `unsigned int` are interchangeable, as long as the value is within the representable range of both types. (For a typical 32-bit system, that means the value has to be in the range 0 to 2<sup>31</sup>-1; `int` values from -2<sup>31</sup> to -1, and `unsigned int` values from 2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>32</sup>-1, are outside the range of the other type, and are not interchangeable.)

But footnotes in the C standard are *non-normative*. They are generally intended to clarify requirements stated in the normative text, not to impose new requirements. But the normative text here merely states that corresponding signed and unsigned types have the same representation, which doesn't *necessarily* imply that they're passed the same way as function arguments. In principle, a compiler *could* ignore that footnote and, for example, pass `int` and `unsigned int` arguments in different registers, making `fprintf(fp, "%c\n", foo);` undefined.

But in practice, there's no reason for an implementation to play that kind of game, and you can rely on `fprintf(fp, "%c\n", foo);` to work as expected. I've never seen or heard of an implementation where it wouldn't work.

Personally, I prefer not to rely on that. If I were writing that code, I'd add an explicit conversion, via a cast, just so these questions don't arise in the first place:

```
unsigned int foo = 42;
fprintf(fp, "%c\n", (int)foo);
```

Or I'd make `foo` an `int` in the first place.

Comment: When you state that my example "actually has well-defined behavior", are you saying that it is well-defined for my specific value of `42`, while possibly undefined for values outside of the range representable by `int`?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: Yes. It's well defined (if we pretend the footnote is normative) if and only if the value is with the ranges of both `int` and `unsigned int`.

Comment: @KeithThompson C also says the size and alignment of an `unsigned int` and `int` are the same in *p6) "For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned integer type [...] that uses the same amount of storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements"* Although there is probably no chance using `unsigned int` would fail, it is technically UB because it clearly violates 7.1.4p1 *"If an argument to a function has [...] a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined"*

Comment: @KeithThompson Regarding the excerpt: `the very rare case that plain char is signed`, do you mean "unsigned" rather than "signed?"

Comment: @VilhelmGray: Yes, fixed, thanks! (To anyone reading these comments: the rare case isn't that plain `char` is unsigned, it's that plain `char` is unsigned *and* `sizeof (int) == 1`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Therefore, explicitly passing a `signed char` variable should not result in undefined behavior since it's range of values is a subset of `int`'s range of values?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: Yes, I believe that's correct. Passing a `char` variable will *almost* never result in undefined behavior. In fact, I've never heard of a *hosted* implementation with `CHAR_BIT > 8`, and only hosted implementations are required to implement `fprintf`.

Answer (score 5):

`%c` conversion specification for `fprintf` requires an `int` argument. The value has to be of type `int` after the *default argument promotions*.

```
unsigned int foo = 42;
fprintf(fp, "%c\n", foo);
```

undefined behavior: `foo` has to be an `int`.

```
char bar = 'B';
fprintf(fp, "%c\n", bar);
```

not undefined behavior:`bar` is promoted (default argument promotions) to `int` as `fprintf` is a variadic function.

**EDIT:** to be fair, there are still some *very rare* implementations where it can be undefined behavior. For example, if `char` is an unsigned type with not all `char` values representable in an `int` (like in [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17882460/1119701)), the default argument promotion is done to `unsigned int`.

Comment: I think the OP was specifically worried about `char` unsigned and as wide as `int`, in which case `bar` is promoted to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @ouah Wouldn't *default argument promotions* for a `char` fall in the `integer promotions are performed on each argument` category of **section 6.5.2.2** paragraph 6?

Comment: I would be curious to know what glyph such an implementation would print for `CHAR_MAX` :)

Comment: @VilhelmGray yes, I'm referring to this paragraph for the default argument promotions.

Comment: I wonder if the more current C standards have addressed this potential UB. Though since this probably only occurs on rare cases, it may not warrant a change even if they knew about it.

Comment: @JensGustedt I'd think all implementations with `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` are freestanding implementations and freestanding implementations are not required to include the standard IO library. So I would think `fprintf` may be just not available on these implementations.