# unsigned char output of a signed char

Tags: c, types

I have the following code:

```
char x = -1;
int y = x;

printf("%u\n", x);
printf("%u\n", y);
```

The output is:

```
4294967295
4294967295
```

I dont understand why x can get such a value. I know that the maximum value of a unsigned char is 255 and for a signed char 127. How can it be 4294967295?

Comment: Assuming that `char` is signed on your platform, then this is *undefined behaviour* - you're passing a signed value to `printf`, but telling it to expect (via `%u`) an unsigned value.

Comment: It is undefined behavior b/c you are using the incorrect format specificer but also [variadic function promote their arguments to wider types as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28097654/1708801) ... `bool, char, short, and unscoped enumerations are converted to int or wider integer types as in integer promotion`

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: FWIW, the same output could also occur on rare (unicorn?) platforms with with `char` as a 32-bit `unsigned char` and 32-bit `int/unsigned`.  In that case `printf("%u\n", x);` is well defined and output `"4294967295\n"` is expected.

Answer (score 2):

For functions like `printf` that use variadic arguments, any integral types smaller than an `int` (`char` and `short`) are implicitly promoted to `int`. The same is true with floating-point numbers, `float` is promoted to `double`.

Hence, your `char` is being sign-extended to an `int` with value `-1`, and since you are printing it as unsigned, in 2's complement you get `UINT_MAX`.

Edit: as chux notes below, if your `char` defaulted to unsigned (this depends on your compiler/platform), the answer would be `255` instead. When promotion occurs, the value will be zero-extended instead of sign-extended.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yep, just fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: As others have noted, although two’s complement explains why OP got this particular result, the behavior is actually undefined.

Comment: Although "char is being sign-extended to an int with value -1" may apply in this case, `char` may be unsigned and output could be `"255\n"`.

Comment: "any integral types smaller than an int" ?  if input is unsigned char than also it should promoted to int ? It's not.

Comment: @achal: C 2011 [N1570] 6.3.1.1 2: “If an **int** can represent all values of the original type (…), the value is converted to an **int**; otherwise it is converted to an **unsigned int**.” In most C implementations `unsigned char` is narrower than `int`, although [not always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882326/is-unsigned-char-always-promoted-to-int).

Answer (score 0):

The variable has the -1 value.
but you specified that %u(unsigned int) in the printf

int is 32bit so
2^32 = 4294967296 => -1 + 4294967296 =4294967295
hope you understand this.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing a format specifier and invoking undefined behavior because of that.My understanding is that in each case, the number of converted to its two's compliment binary representation which is same for -1 or 4294967295. That is why %u for signed prints 4294967295 by ignoring -ve leftmost bit. When used %d for signed int, it uses left most bit as -ve flag and prints -1. Similarly %u for unsigned prints unsigned value but %d causes it to treat the number as signed and thus prints -1

Answer (score -1):

If your input qualifier is `signed`, be careful of sign bit, if sign bit is 1, you will get negative value.  Though `x` is `signed char`, you are expecting `1 byte` value but you are getting `4 byte` value because of **sign bit copy** mechanism.

**x** value :

```
x =  -1 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111  1111
                                        |
                                        sign bit, this bit get's copied into remaining bytes, so it becomes like

        = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 11111 1111 1111 => calculates this => 4294967295 
        = |
         sign bit , now you are printing  in %u format i.e unsigned so it will ignore signed bit and you are getting big value.
```

Same if you are printing in `%d` or `%i` format

```
printf("%d\n", x); // it prints -1 bcz %d will check sign bit which is 1 i.e it will prints -ve value, so it's prints -1
```

I just tried to explains why you are getting such output but It's `undefined behaviour` as mentioned in some comments if you are not using correct format specifier. you can  refer different C standard.

EDIT : to justify my point(linux machine) let's consider below code

```
int main()
{
        unsigned char x = -1;
        printf("%u\n",x);
        /*In above printf input is unsigned, so compiler won't 
         check sign bit, even though sign bit is 1, result 
        will be +ve only. */

        printf("%d\n",x);//some of you may expects -1 because of %d, it's wrong.
       /* In above printf it's printing 255 not because of format 
        specifier, it's because of your input qualifier(which is 
        unsigned in this case) */

        return 0;
}
```