# Is there any hosted C implementations which have CHAR_BIT > 8?

Tags: c

Follow-up question for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63909222/1778275.) answer.

Is there any hosted C implementations (`__STDC_HOSTED__` is 1) which have `CHAR_BIT > 8`?

If so, then which ones?

UPD. Fix typo: before: `__STDC_HOSTED__` is `0`, after: `__STDC_HOSTED__` is `1`.

Comment: Do you want a real implementation running on a commercial computer  hardware which could be bought in 2021, or is a "virtual machine" acceptable?

Comment: Wouldn't that imply an architecture with not 8-bit bytes?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch. And in the latter case, do you accept something someone threw together just to prove a point?

Comment: You could make such a bizarre architecture with FPGA, but it won't be cost-effective

Comment: Is this relevant: [What platforms have something other than 8-bit char?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2098149/10871073)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: today http://www.madphysicist.com/ is not responding on Sun 14 Mar 2021 05:23:12 PM UTC

Comment: Any such implementation could not claim POSIX conformance (see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_23_03_06) and probably couldn't run any current-generation generic embedded OS either, so there's a great deal of incentive for hardware designers to avoid doing things that would necessitate a larger CHAR_BIT.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thre's nothing in the C standard that says that the number of bits in `char` has to be 8.

Comment: @JeremyP. No, only that a `char` be one byte, hence my comment.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: C implementations do not have to directly use the bytes or other features of the architecture their programs execute on. It is reasonable for a C implementation to provide a model suitable to some old or special purpose C code.

Comment: @AdrianMole Sure, `__STDC_HOSTED__` is `1`. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there was ever a post-standardisation version, but various Cray 64-bit vector supercomputers had a C compiler in which `sizeof(long) == sizeof(double) == 1`, a.k.a. *everything is 64 bits wide*.

Comment: IIRC, `char*` was a type incompatible with `int*`. And `sizeof(char*)` was different of `sizeof(int*)`