# If sizeof(int) == sizeof(long), then is INT_MIN == LONG_MIN && INT_MAX == LONG_MAX always true?

Tags: c, integer, range, sizeof, c11

If `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`, then is `INT_MIN == LONG_MIN && INT_MAX == LONG_MAX` always true?

Is there any real existing cases demonstrating "not true"?

UPD. The similar question: [Is there any hosted C implementations which have CHAR_BIT > 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627420/is-there-any-hosted-c-implementations-which-have-char-bit-8).

Comment: One could imagine a computer and a mad compiler writer that used 2's complement for ints and sign-magnitude for longs.  But no real-world examples.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to know if you can rely on that?

Comment: @stark Apparently, ones-complement and sign-and-magnitude representations of signed integers are going to be abandoned in the next version of the C standard.

Comment: [*The New C Standard*](http://www.coding-guidelines.com/cbook/cbook1_2.pdf) on page 594 says there were Cray implementations where `short` was a 32-bit type occupying 64 bits of space.  In that case, it might have had `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)` but `SHORT_MAX < INT_MAX`.

Comment: I think it's a safe assumption on any hosted implementation, but that's not a guarantee.  C allows implementations to do weird things with type sizes and representations, and there's always some oddball, niche architecture that has to do things differently.

Comment: @NateEldredge wonder how many of those "cray implementations" are still in use...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It need not be true. [C11 6.2.6.2p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p2):

> 2. For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three groups: value bits, **padding bits**, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits; signed char shall not have any padding bits.There shall be exactly one sign bit. Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M <= N ). If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value. If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the following ways:
>
>    - the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);
>    - the sign bit has the value -(2<sup>M</sup>) (two's complement);
>    - the sign bit has the value -(2<sup>M</sup>- 1) (ones' complement).
>
>    Which of these applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1 and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones' complement), is a trap representation or a normal value. In the case of sign and magnitude and ones' complement, if this representation is a normal value it is called a negative zero.

---

Now, the question is "is there any implementation that has different amount of padding bits" or, even as [stark mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69631470/if-sizeofint-sizeoflong-then-int-min-long-min-int-max-long-max#comment123077784_69631470), different representations for different types of integers - it is very hard to prove that there is no such implementation currently in use. But I believe it is very unlikely that one would come across a system like this in real life.